# What is HttpHeaders and why is it used in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am new to the angular framework. I have a requirement to post some form's data to the server using webApi. While I was trying to submit the form, I looked through few topics like HttpClientModule. But I was stuck at HttpHeaders. I wanted to know how does it help while submitting or receiving data from/to the server.

But I haven't found any resources that explain this.

Could anyone help me in understanding the concepts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

From [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/http#http-headers)

> Many servers require extra headers for save operations. For example,
>   they may require a "Content-Type" header to explicitly declare the
>   MIME type of the request body; or the server may require an
>   authorization token.

Http headers is need to authenticate the request, if you have token in your header and the backend will verify your API to check if you are authenticate to get the Response.

Example:
create httpOptions with your headers in your component.ts

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};
```

and use it for when you request through http methods such as get, post, put, delete etc.

```
return this.http.get<>(thisurl, httpOptions).subscribe();
```

Or you can use Interceptor to do it globally. Follow the [link](https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2017/07/19/angular-new-http-interface-with-interceptors/)

Comment: Can you please add the source for the quote at the start of your answer?